# Combine navigation and footer routes into one place

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an app with navigation, main part and footer where I used react-router-dom. Navigation is made up of Navlink. Footer is made up of Link. Main part of website should be grouping all routers.

I want to be able to get pages when clicking on navigation and footer links. They all should render to main part of app.

I represented routes as 2 objects.

Have a look at Main component. Is it possible to map these objects and get multiple routes that way?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {HashRouter, Route, Switch, Link, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <h1>Welcome to the company</h1>;
const Service = () => <h1>We are providing quality services</h1>;
const Delivery = () => <h1>Delivery time is about ten days</h1>;
const Contacts = () => <h1>Please call me during working hours</h1>;
const Partners = () => <h1>Our partners are biggest manufacturers</h1>;
const Information = () => <h1>Please read that info</h1>;
const Tags = () => <h1>Here is the tag list</h1>;
const About = () => <h1>Some info about photos</h1>;
const More = () => <h1>To find out more please read that</h1>;

/**
 * Navigation
 */

var linkStyle = { display: 'inline-block', float: 'left' };
var navigationStyle = { height: '45px', lineHeight: '45px' };

const menus = [
    {path: '/', component: Home, name: 'Home' }, 
    {path: '/service', component: Service, name: 'Service' }, 
    {path: '/delivery', component: Delivery, name: 'Delivery' },
    {path: '/contacts', component: Contacts, name: 'Contacts' }, 
    {path: '/partners', component: Partners, name: 'Partners' },
    {path: '/information', component: Information, name: 'Information' }
];



function Navigation() {
  const listItems = menus.map(({path, component, name}, key) => <li style={linkStyle} key={key}><NavLink activeStyle={{outline:'none', color: 'red'}} to={path}>{name}</NavLink></li> );
  return (
    <div style={navigationStyle}><ul>{listItems}</ul></div>
  );
}

/**
 * Footer
 */

const routes = [
    {path: '/tags', component: Tags, name: 'Tags' }, 
    {path: '/about', component: About, name: 'About' }, 
    {path: '/more', component: More, name: 'More' }
];


function FooterList() {
  const listItems = routes.map(({path, component, name}, key) => <li key={key}><Link to={path}>{name}</Link></li> );
  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}


function Main()  {
    const routeComponents = routes.map(({path, component}, key) => <Route exact path={path} component={component} key={key} />);
    const menuComponents = menus.map(({path, component}, key) => <Route exact path={path} component={component} key={key} />);
    return (
      <Switch>{routeComponents}{menuComponents}</Switch>
    );
}

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navigation />
            <Main />
            <FooterList />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<HashRouter><App/></HashRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: If this helps be sure to mark the answer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Main()  {
    const routeComponents = routes.map(({path, component}, key) => <Route exact path={path} component={component} key={key} />);
    const menuComponents = menus.map(({path, component}, key) => <Route exact path={path} component={component} key={key} />);
    const allComponents = routeComponents.concat(menuComponents);
    return <Switch>{allComponents}</Switch>;
}

// To combine and THEN map
const routeComponents = ( routes.concat(menus) ).map( ({ path, component }, key ) => <Route exact path={path} component={component} key={key} />);
```

Comment: Yes it works. Getting two arrays together. I thought it is possible somehow to get two arrays together before mapping

Comment: Sure. Do the concat BEFORE the map.

`const allComponents = ( routes.concat(menus) ).map( ({ path, component }, key ) => <Route exact path={path} component={component} key={key} />);`

Comment: That's fantastic. I like the second one better